# Can't get NServiceBus running under custom service account?

Tags: c#, msmq, nservicebus, windows-server-2012

I've created a bare-bones NServiceBus endpoint (which doesn't do anything for now), and when I install it (using `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /displayName:"MyEndpoint"`), it gets installed as a service
that runs under Local Service, and it works perfectly.

Now, when I change the Run as account for this Windows Service to my own local service account (lets call it "svcTestAccount" for now, it has Logon as a service permission), the service starts and *then unexpectedly stops halfway during its initialization*.

I can't tell why, since no exceptions get logged to log4net, the process just terminates.
I've seen this behaviour before in a previous project when the endpoint couldn't access the queue it needed, but this time I have configured the 5 queues that my endpoint to give "Everyone" "Full Control", so it shouldn't be that, right?

What's strange is that, when I run it (using the NServiceBus.Host.exe on production profile), it happily runs in all the following situations:

- From within Visual Studio 2012, running as local admin.
- As a windows service, running under Local Service
- As a windows service, running under Network Service
- As a windows service, running under svcTestAccount, if svcTestAccount is a member of the local Administrators group.
- From a command prompt running under svcTestAccount (i.e. "runas /user:svcTestAccount cmd" to open the command prompt, then NServiceBus.Host.exe to run my endpoint)

The only thing that doesn't work is getting it to run as a Windows Service under svcTestAccount (and not being a member of the local Administrators group).

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

For completeness sake, my endpoint only consists of:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .Log4Net();
    }
}
```

And my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>

    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
</configuration>
```

I'm using NServiceBus 4.3.0 on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: does the svcTestAccount account have access to write to the folder the service is running from? It's possible that log4net can't create a log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run NServiceBus host as a different account (not Local System) you need to execute the installer with `/username` and `/password`, eg:

`NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /displayName:"MyEndpoint" /username:"mydomain\username" /password:"mysecretpassword"`

See http://docs.particular.net/NServiceBus/the-nservicebus-host#installation for more info.

Comment: This was the solution - apparently, the NServiceBus.Host installer adds the specified user to a "Performance Monitor Users" group (and maybe does some other things with it as well). This means that you can't just install the service under Local Service and then change the Logon As credentials, because you won't get these extra permissions. 
I wish the logging would be clearer about this, though.

Comment: Correct, the install also sets up permissions for the queues as well. We'll try to highlight this in our doco!

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund: Thanks, hopefully that will prevent others from falling into the same trap.
But the first place I looked was in the logs (the first part of the initialization gets logged perfectly), and I was surprised to find that this error was (apparently) so severe that the endpoint didn't get the chance to log an error, and the process just terminates. Is it supposed to behave like this?

Comment: That sound vierd. Logging is the first thing we setup. I'll see if I can figure out why